# codeigniter validate

Tags: codeigniter, validation

Hello I have a forum and when a user creates a comment, I want that if he didn't type anything I want to show him an error that he must type something in :) but I dont know how to put him the the thread he is in.

I have this

```
if($this->_submit_validate_comment() == false) {
   $this->post(); return;
}

function _submit_validate_comment() {
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('kommentar', 'kommentar', 'required|min_length[4]');
  return $this->form_validation->run();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with jquery but if that is not an option you could get the forum or topic id from the url (assuming your are using the url this way).

For example:

http://yoursite.com/forum/topic/12

```
if($this->_submit_validate_comment() == false) 
{ 
    $topic_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    redirect('/forum/topic/'. $topic_id);
}
```

Or

```
if($this->_submit_validate_comment() == false) 
{ 
    $topic_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->topic($topic_id);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In your redirect method you are using /forum/post/'. $this->input->post('id') and your base url is  localhost:8888/ci/. It could be an issue with the url. Try adding base_url() . '/forum/post/'.... to your redirect to see if that helps. I could be wrong but try changing the uri segment from 3 to 4 just in case, or better yet echo out the value of $this->uri->segment(3) to make sure you are getting the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping i can see what you mean but it just dont work :b,

i have this

$topic_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$this->post($topic_id);
return;

and my url is

localhost:8888/ci/index.php/forum/create_comment

it looks like it cant find the ID

my URL to the forum is
localhost:8888/ci/index.php/forum/post/33

this is my functions

> function create_comment()  {
>     if($this->_submit_validate_comment()
>   == false) {    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
>      $this->post($id);    return;
>      //echo "validate fejl, kontakt lige
>   en admin!";   } else {    $data =
>   array(    'fk_forum_traad' =>
>   $this->input->post('id'),
>      'brugernavn'     =>
>   $this->session->userdata('username'),
>      'indhold'        =>
>   $this->input->post('kommentar'),
>      'dato'        => 'fejl'    );
>
> $this->load->model('forum_model');
>     $this->forum_model->create_comment($data);
>     redirect('/forum/post/'.
>   $this->input->post('id').'',
>   'refresh');   }
>       }
>
> function post($id)  {
>     $this->load->model('forum_model');
>     $data['query'] =
>   $this->forum_model->posts($this->uri->segment(3));
>
> $this->load->model('forum_model');
>     $data['comments'] =
>   $this->forum_model->comments($this->uri->segment(3));
>
> ```
>  $data['content'] = 'forum_post_view';
> ```
>
> $this->load->view('includes/template',
>   $data);  }

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass in the return uri in the form submission using a hidden input field? No additional work will be needed by the controller other than validation of the return uri before performing a redirect.

Place the validation error string in session class's flashdata for echoing out in the form, along with any other data used to pre-populate your form)